# How to link a model to a router's routes

Tags: backbone.js

I know this is a beginner question, but I read the doc, some tutorials, and I still have a hard time making it work.

I have a simple php rest webservice, you can see the declared urls:

```
$app->get('/todos', 'getTodos');
$app->post('/todo/add', 'addTodo');
$app->put('/todo/update/:id', 'updateTodo');
$app->delete('/todo/delete/:id','deleteTodo');
```

Here is my backbone router:

```
var app.myRouteur = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
      "todos":                "get",
      "todo/add":             "add",  
      "todo/update/:id":      "update",
      "todo/delete/:id"       "delete"
    },

  get: function() {
    alert('get route triggered');
  },

  add: function() {

  },

  update: function(id) {

  },

  delete: function(id) {

  }

});
```

The router is instanciated as such:

```
var app = app || {};
var ENTER_KEY = 13;

$(function() {
  new app.myRouteur();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/api/index.php/"});
  new app.AppView();
});
```

My question is: what should I do so that the models automatically use those routes to communicate with the webservice?
Is this router supposed to define the webservice's urls or only backbone internal urls (and then webservice's urls should be declared in the model)?

I'm a bit lost and confused... not knowing what do to with this router...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- The Router's routes are here just to organize your application and centerlize the workflow between you views. You can access them by  tags or using Backbone.History.navigate() ...

2- The responsables of accessing your webservices are models with `urlRoot` and collections with `url`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Rida, it's weird but I didn't grasp this little piece of information on the tutorials I read, seing many examples without any router at all and without calls to external urls (local storage instead)